# applying function on rdd.foreach pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, foreach, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to apply send_active_mq on each row of an rdd.

```
def send_to_active_mq(json_string) :
   k = str(json_string)
   conn.send(body=k,destination='dwEmailsQueue2')

json_rdd_to_send.foreach(send_to_active_mq)
```

I applied the same way as suggested in the spark documentation 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#foreach

But I am getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong I am doing here.

Comment: What version of spark are you using? 1.5.0 was affected by some serialization issues that look similiar to yours: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10542

Comment: I am using spark 1.6.1

Comment: OK, and what type of data this RDD contains? If this is a dict, check types of all dict's keys and values.

Comment: It is RDD[String] . I have no idea about dict though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably connected to `conn` object. Try:

```
def send_to_active_mq(json_strings):
    conn = ... # Initalize connection
    for json_string in json_strings:
        conn.send(body=str(json_string) ,destination='dwEmailsQueue2')

json_rdd_to_send.foreachPartition(send_to_active_mq)
```

Comment: I tried the above approach, it is working fine but the problem here is foreachpartition I am opening a new connection sending data and closing it. is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This is the only way to do it. There is no shared state in PySpark.